# angular8- surveyjs-how to remove default complete button

Tags: javascript, angular8, surveyjs

In angular 8 web application, im using survey js. By default complete button is shown. Please advise on how to remove default complete button

Answer (score 1):

That complete button has class like

> sv_complete_btn

sv_complete_btn
In javascript you can use this code

```
$(".sv_complete_btn").remove();
```